# A powershell version of for /f (|findstr) for Unicode folders/files

Tags: windows-7, powershell, cmd.exe, unicode, findstr

Here is a small script I wrote that recursively scan a directory without some parent-subdirectories and extracts some attributes of the files within it.

```
@echo off
echo Path,Name,Extension,Size > filelist.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir D:\שער /A:-d /s /b ^| findstr /l /i /v ^/c:"קקק" ^/c:"ttt"') 
do echo %%~dpi,%%~ni,%%~xi,%%~zi >> filelist.txt
```

The problem is that findstr doesn't support Unicode chars (hebrew in this case, for /f does if you change the console font).

What is the PowerShell version of this script (assuming that PS loop does support unicode chars) ?

Thank you

Comment: Just a nitpick: from the title it looks like UTF is about the *conetnts* of the files, since UTF is a file encoding/format. IMHO it would be better to say "Unicode paths" instead of "UTF folders/files".

Comment: There are no "UTF" chars. UTF-8/16/32 are encoding schemes for Unicode and Windows uses UTF-16. [`findstr` doesn't support Unicode](https://superuser.com/q/306619/241386) [but `find` does](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `findstr` command is used to search the files content for the `קקק` text, here is the PowerShell code equivalent:

```
Set-Content -Path 'filelist.txt' -Value 'Path,Name,Extension,Size' -Encoding UTF8

foreach( $file in (Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\Temp\שער' -Recurse) )
{
    $nameCount = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8 | Select-String -Pattern 'קקק' | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

    if( $nameCount -gt 0 )
    {
        $line =  $file.DirectoryName + ',' + $file.BaseName + ',' + $file.Extension + ',' + $file.Length
        Add-Content -Path 'filelist.txt' -Value $line -Encoding UTF8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `findstr`, and solved it by using `Select-String` instead of `findstr`.

`cat .\log*.txt | findstr -I Error` was buggy, but `cat .\log*.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'Error'` was working fine.