# How to search text written in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I want to find the necessary attribute through the command's help output. How to do it? Output like this:
[help output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKrCe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are looking for the /H switch:

Program.exe /? |find /i "/h"

Program.exe --help |find /i "/H"

That should only show you the line where there is an "/H" occurrence.

Some programas also accept:

program.exe /h /?
program.exe /h --help

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I want to find the flags available for the a command within the terminal. For brevity, let's pick "replace".

You can type either of the following:

```
help replace | findstr "\/" 
help replace | find "/"
```

to find all lines that have a forward slash (backslash is used to escape the forward slash).

---

Below an example with findstr and regex to filter network connections:

```
 netstat -n | findstr -r "127.*"
```

Both find and findstr serve the same purpose but findstr is newer and supports regex. To learn about the difference, you can check this answer in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/306619/whats-the-difference-between-the-find-and-findstr-commands-in-windows).

[image: Image showing output of help replace | findstr "/"]